# InputBox Variable not being recognized in Countif Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Macro to use countif and do calculations with data in Rows represented by various years. I would like to be able to set the year searched for in a input box so that you can change what year your searching for on a case by case basis. my variable is not carrying over into the formula.

```
Sub FullGiftCalculation()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim xYear As Integer 
    xYear = InputBox("What is the Campaign Year?")

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Select

        ActiveSheet.Range("T10").Value = "Total Constituents"
        ActiveSheet.Range("T11").Value = "Total Gifts Open"
        ActiveSheet.Range("T12").Value = "Total Gifts Closed"
        ActiveSheet.Range("T13").Value = "% Closed"
        ActiveSheet.Range("V10").Formula = "=countif(B1:B5000,xYear)"
        ActiveSheet.Range("V12").Formula = "=countifs(B1:B5000,xYear,E1:E5000,""C-Pledged"")"
        ActiveSheet.Range("V11").Formula = "=V10-V12"
        ActiveSheet.Range("V13").Formula = "=V12/V10"
        Range("V13").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    Next ws    
End Sub
```

When I step int the macro i can see my set variable when i hover over the line "xYear = ...." but not in my formulas. the outputs when run are zeros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you place the formula through VBA, you place the formula in the form of a String e.g.

"=countif(B1:B5000,**xYear**)"

But as you can see in the above String, xYear is a variable and when you need to add a variable in any string you need to concatenate the variable using the & symbol and you do it like this...

"=countif(B1:B5000," **& xYear &** ")"

i.e. you break the string in two parts...

"=countif(B1:B5000," and ")" and you place your variable in between both the string parts using the string concatenation symbol & on both side of the variable.

As far as your code is concerned, you even need not to select the worksheet if you want to place the same formulas on each available worksheet in the workbook.

You may simply try the below code...

```
Sub FullGiftCalculation()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim xYear As Integer
    xYear = InputBox("What is the Campaign Year?")
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws
            .Range("T10").Value = "Total Constituents"
            .Range("T11").Value = "Total Gifts Open"
            .Range("T12").Value = "Total Gifts Closed"
            .Range("T13").Value = "% Closed"
            .Range("V10").Formula = "=countif(B1:B5000," & xYear & ")"
            .Range("V12").Formula = "=countifs(B1:B5000," & xYear & ",E1:E5000,""C-Pledged"")"
            .Range("V11").Formula = "=V10-V12"
            .Range("V13").Formula = "=V12/V10"
            .Range("V13").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the Explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the variable value into the forumla like below:

```
Sub FullGiftCalculation()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim xYear As Integer 
    xYear = InputBox("What is the Campaign Year?")

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Select

        ActiveSheet.Range("T10").Value = "Total Constituents"
        ActiveSheet.Range("T11").Value = "Total Gifts Open"
        ActiveSheet.Range("T12").Value = "Total Gifts Closed"
        ActiveSheet.Range("T13").Value = "% Closed"
        ActiveSheet.Range("V10").Formula = "=countif(B1:B5000,"& xYear &")"
        ActiveSheet.Range("V12").Formula = "=countifs(B1:B5000,"& xYear &",E1:E5000,""C-Pledged"")"
        ActiveSheet.Range("V11").Formula = "=V10-V12"
        ActiveSheet.Range("V13").Formula = "=V12/V10"
        Range("V13").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    Next ws    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! do you know the reason behind the specific formatting so i can learn for next time?

Comment: @ZMichelson because in `"=countif(B1:B5000,xYear)"` the `xYear` is not a variable it is a string/text only because it is within quotes. But in `"=countif(B1:B5000,"& xYear &")"` we end quotes first, then concatenate the value of the variable `xYear` with the `&` operator and concatenate the rest of the formula.

Comment: Thank you for the Explanation!